# bitrix как изменить результат после заполнения формы

Tags: php, битрикс

я не очень силен в битре, поэтому вынужден взывать к помощи сообщества. Задача стоит такая, часто при заполнении конкретной формы посетители сайта прописывают случайно/специально лишние символы (пробелы с ковычками) соответственно необходимо результаты после заполнения формы обработать, я перерыл оф.документацию, понял, что нужно добавить функцию-обработчик в init.php, что я и сделал. Но результата нет никакого, я перепробовал уже все что можно, но увы, не работает.

```
addEventHandler('form','onBeforeResultAdd','my_onBeforeResultAdd');

function my_onBeforeResultAdd($WEB_FORM_ID, &$arFields, &$arrVALUES)
{
  
  if ($WEB_FORM_ID == 706) 
  {
    $arrVALUES['name'] = 'test';
  }
}
```

В данном случае я просто хочу добиться работоспособности функции-обработчика, поэтому меняю результат одного из вопросов формы на тест. Помогите, пожалуйста, как решить эту задачу?
Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте вывести в файл то, что приходит в $arrVALUES. Там точно есть значение у индекса name?

Comment: не подскажите, как я могу попробовать вывести этот массив из init.php? я пробовал сделать дамп в командной php-строке внутри инструментария битрикса, но эта командная строка вообще как-то странно работает

Comment: ```file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/706.log', print_r($arrVALUES, 1) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);```